# How to get product image by Amazon Inventory Management ( AIM ) APIs

Tags: image, api, amazon-product-api

How to get product image by Amazon Inventory Management ( AIM ) APIs

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to get product images using the Amazon Inventory Management API. You will need to use the Amazon Product Advertising API to get product features such as images, dimensions, publisher, sales rank etc...

If you are trying to get the product image for, say, every product in a merchant's inventory, you should:

1. Get a list of all items in a merchant's inventory
2. For each item in that list, request the ItemLookup Operation (See doc: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2010-11-01/DG/ItemLookup.html) by passing the ASIN (unique identifier) of the item as the ItemId, and setting the ResponseGroup to "Images".

Your request should look like:

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID]&
Operation=ItemLookup&
ItemId=[Your-ASIN]&
ResponseGroup=Images&
Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]&
Signature=[Request Signature]
```

The response will look like:

```
<Item>
  <ASIN>[Your-ASIN]</ASIN>
  <SmallImage>
    <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/....jpg</URL>
    <Height Units="pixels">75</Height>
    <Width Units="pixels">58</Width>
  </SmallImage>
  <MediumImage>
    <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/....jpg</URL>
    <Height Units="pixels">160</Height>
    <Width Units="pixels">124</Width>
  </MediumImage>
  <LargeImage>
    <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/....jpg</URL>
    <Height Units="pixels">500</Height>
    <Width Units="pixels">389</Width>
  </LargeImage>
</Item>
```

You can easily parse the response to get the URL of the image you want to use.

A few notes:

- If you want to get the product image
  for a different list of products
  (say, all products in orders that
  need to be fulfilled), just change
  step 1 accordingly.
- If you need more details about the
  item, set the ResponseGroup parameter
  with "Medium" or "Large" when
  invoking the ItemLookup operation.
  The Amazon Product Advertising doc
  link given above has all the details.
- You can also get the product image
  directly by constructing its URL
  using the product ASIN. A good
  reference for building the URL can be
  found in
  http://aaugh.com/imageabuse.html.
  This could work as a quick, temporary
  hack, but understand that Amazon may
  block or obfuscate these URL at any
  time.

Comment: can i use MWS product API for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Amazon to Article Info Interface at http://lon.gr/ata/
It generates a XML-File containing the Image URL and other Article information based on the ASIN.

Answer (score 0):

Total disclosure here, I’m Max and I’m the technical co-founder for Zinc (zinc.io). Our API produces a JSON response for both pricing and the product details page. Here’s a typical response for the details of an ASIN: https://www.dropbox.com/s/peccdc1m2j34e0d/B018QPI98A.json?dl=0